# how can i get window's contentView to "hug" it's subViews

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller, autolayout

like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034527), i have an NSView which is the contentView for an NSWindow and it contains several subviews stacked vertically one above the other. some of them are fixed size and some of them can be expanded or collapsed with a disclosure button.

i want to implement a kind of "accordion" effect where expanding or collapsing one of the subviews makes everything else adjust and resizes the superview and the window accordingly.

it really seems like one ought to be able to accomplish this by setting up the right set of constraints with auto layout and i have it now doing the initial layout fine. but i can't figure out how to set up constraints so that the superview automatically re-sizes to hug the sub-views.

the OP in the question linked above never got an answer and provided his own solution like the one that i was starting to implement independently, but i thought i would throw it out there once again in case there are any auto layout gurus that know a trick. it seems like there should be a way to get the superview to hug the subviews by leveraging auto layout without having to manually calculate the sizes of the subviews and manually reset the size of the superview.

anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autolayout is cool and comprehensive. And arcane.

I tried hard but could not come up with a set of constraints that would do what I wanted to do. It still seems to me that if you stack some NSView's vertically inside a superview and set up the constraints such that the top subview is pinned to the top of the superview and going down the stack of subviews you pin each one's top to the bottom edge of the one above and then finally you pin the bottom edge of the last subview to the bottom edge of the superview and you then programmatically resize one or more of the subviews it should be able to pull up or push down on the bottom of the superview to keep it hugging its subviews.

Everything works as expected except for the last piece. When you try to pin the bottom subview to the bottom of the superview, auto layout can't satisfy all the constraints. It seems like resizing the superview to satisfy the constraints is not in the algorithm. Either that or I am missing some other constraint that needs setting.

And while I am on the subject, looking at the debugger, it appears that there are un-settable constrains at play between a window's contentView and the window frame. I kind of wonder if being able to mess with those constraints would let the original scheme work.

Anyway, I did come up with a solution that uses autolayout and it is pretty close to what I was hoping autolayout would do because all that was necessary was subclassing NSView and putting a few lines of code into the intrinsicSize method and then using that subclass for the superview.

i created an xcode project that has my collapsible views base classes and a working demo of the whole thing on [github](https://github.com/PlexusLLC/PLXCollapsibleView).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that in a situation like yours, automatic constraints installed by Xcode on its own can break the layout. For instance, if your variable vertical view does not have an explicit constraint, chances are that IB will add an automatic one to make the layout unambiguous. Later, when you try changing that view's size by installing another constraint on it, you will get an auto-layout error.

One of possible solutions (short of implementing `-intrinsicContentSize` and/or other subclassing) is to hunt down in IB all automatic constraints, which may interfere with your layout and try setting explicit ones in their place with lower priorities. This does not work all the time, though.

The other brutal solution is to remove ALL constraints in your `-awakeFromNib` and then set only those that you need. You can, of course, try removing programmatically only those constraints that stand in your way, but this is not robust, because the next time you change something in the .xib, the problem may reappear in a completely different place.

Typically, I had to do a bit of both to have everything working properly.

Comment: I did remove all the constraints in -awakeFromNib and programmatically create the ones I wanted. I remain convinced that there are constraints between the window frame and the window contentView that are outside of my/our control which mess with you in edge cases like this. In any case, the solution I put on github referenced in my answer above (with subclassed NSView, over-ridden intrinsicContentSize) is working ok for me.

Comment: The only situation, in which I had problems with constraints between the window frame and the content view was when I enabled the inspector bar for a text view, but that was some kind of bug, I suppose. I have almost the same configuration as yours (a sort of vertical accordion implemented entirely with constraints, I did not have to implement `-intrinsicContentSize`, but I did have to play with priorities.